# Push notification from python to iPhone, how to debug?

Tags: iphone, python, push-notification

How do one debug the connection from a provider to Apple push notification server?

I'm using a library called PyAPNs ([github repo](https://github.com/simonwhitaker/PyAPNs)) and have the code below:

```
from apns import APNs, Payload

print "start"

apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='apns-prod.pem', key_file='apns-prod.pem')

# Send a notification
token_hex = '*******'
payload = Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default", badge=1)
apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)

# Get feedback messages
for (token_hex, fail_time) in apns.feedback_server.items():
    print token_hex
    print fail_time


print "end"
```

The application is registered to receive RemoteNotification an everything looks okey under notification settings in the iPhone. But not notifications shows up.

My questions here how can I debug this. When running the script I don't get any errors and the `apns.feedback_server.items` is empty. I've tried to print the buffer from the feedback serve, but nothing.

Is there a way to see what's happening in the SSL socket? Or get some response from apples servers?

..fredrik

**EDIT**

I solved the problem. The issues was with the token_hex. I used the identifier number from the xcode organizer and not the token generated when registering the application.

Comment: There is a problem with your code sample: ``token_hex = '*****'**'`` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a type-o when I removed the real token_hex in the post.

Comment: when you generated the device key your app was deployed in the iphone using which certificate?! Dev or Dist?!

Comment: Dev cert. And the app is built in debug mode using code-sign with the dev cert.

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import socket
import ssl
import json
import struct
import argparse



APNS_HOST = ( 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 2195 )


class Payload:
    PAYLOAD = '{"aps":{${MESSAGE}${BADGE}${SOUND}}}'
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_message(self, msg):
        if msg is None:
            self.PAYLOAD = self.PAYLOAD.replace('${MESSAGE}', '')
        else:
            self.PAYLOAD = self.PAYLOAD.replace('${MESSAGE}', '"alert":"%s",' % msg)

    def set_badge(self, num):
        if num is None:
            self.PAYLOAD = self.PAYLOAD.replace('${BADGE}', '')
        else:
            self.PAYLOAD = self.PAYLOAD.replace('${BADGE}', '"badge":%s,' % num)

    def set_sound(self, sound):
        if sound is None:
            self.PAYLOAD = self.PAYLOAD.replace('${SOUND}', '')
        else:
            self.PAYLOAD = self.PAYLOAD.replace('${SOUND}', '"sound":"%s",' % sound)

    def toString(self):
        return (self.PAYLOAD.replace('${MESSAGE}','').replace('${BADGE}','').replace('${SOUND}',''))

def connectAPNS(host, cert):
    ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket( socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ), certfile = cert )
    ssl_sock.connect( APNS_HOST )
    return ssl_sock

def sendNotification(sslSock, device, message, badge, sound):
    payload = Payload()
    payload.set_message(message)
    payload.set_badge(badge)
    payload.set_sound(sound)
    payloadAsStr = payload.toString()

    format = '!BH32sH%ds' % len(payloadAsStr)
    binaryDeviceToken = device.replace(' ','').decode('hex')
    binaryNotification = struct.pack( format, 0, 32, binaryDeviceToken, len(payloadAsStr), payloadAsStr )

    print ("sending payload: ["+payloadAsStr+"] as binary to device: ["+device+"]")
    sslSock.write(binaryNotification)

def printUsageAndExit():
    print("msg2ios - Version 0.1\nmsg2IOS.py -d <device> -m <message> -s[plays sound] -b <badgeint>  -c <certBundlePath>")
    exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--device')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--message')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--sound')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--badge')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--cert')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if (args.device is None) or ((args.message is None) and (args.sound is None) and (args.badge is None)) or (args.cert is None):
        printUsageAndExit()

    sslSock = connectAPNS(APNS_HOST, args.cert)
    sendNotification(sslSock, args.device, args.message, args.badge, args.sound)
    sslSock.close()
```

Comment: Some explanation here would be helpful.